# Button click Open richTextBox and display the readfile

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have 2 buttons and I read different files when I click on these buttons. I used the to display the readfile using `MsgBox`  since the files are big, so i want to display it in a `richTextBox`.

How can I open a `richTextBox` and display the `read file` when I click on any one of these buttons???

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    DisplayFile(FileSelected);//DisplayFile is the path of the file
    var ReadFile = XDocument.Load(FileSelected); //Read the selected file to display

    MessageBox.Show("The Selected" + " " + FileSelected + " " + "File Contains :" + "\n " + "\n " + ReadFile);
    button1.Enabled = false;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileInfo file = (FileInfo)comboBox2.SelectedItem;
    StreamReader FileRead = new StreamReader(file.FullName);
    string FileBuffer = FileRead.ReadToEnd(); //Read the selected file to display

    //MessageBox.Show("The Selected" + " " + file + " " +"File Contains :"  + "\n " + "\n " + FileBuffer);
    // richTextBox1.AppendText("The Selected" + " " + file + " " + "File Contains :" + "\n " + "\n " + FileBuffer);
    //richTextBox1.Text = FileBuffer;
}
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: So, you want to show a richtextbox in a messagebox, right?

Comment: create new form, and put only RichTextBox on it and maybe close button, and then show it on button click

Comment: @ Krishanu Dey: yes, if it's a big file then i want to scroll...

Comment: The built-in MessageBox does not support that. You need create your own window and show in modal mode (setting the owner property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example (code based form design). It's better if you create the form via the GUI designer:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //test call of the rtBox
    ShowRichMessageBox("Test", File.ReadAllText("test.txt"));
}

/// <summary>
/// Shows a Rich Text Message Box
/// </summary>
/// <param name="title">Title of the box</param>
/// <param name="message">Message of the box</param>
private void ShowRichMessageBox(string title, string message)
{
    RichTextBox rtbMessage = new RichTextBox();
    rtbMessage.Text = message;
    rtbMessage.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    rtbMessage.ReadOnly = true;
    rtbMessage.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

    Form RichMessageBox = new Form();
    RichMessageBox.Text = title;
    RichMessageBox.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

    RichMessageBox.Controls.Add(rtbMessage);
    RichMessageBox.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: it looks great, is there way to call the selected file-name in the `title` and increase the font???

Comment: Of course, you have to use the `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)` method to get the name of the file and pass it as the title. To increase the font size you have to set a new font like this: `rtbMessage.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20f);`

Comment: Genial, `rtbMessage.Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);`Merci